# Rep-tiles of order 4 and order 9

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, tiling

Rep-tiles are figures which are dissected by the same figures as itself.

[image: Examples of rep-tiles]

As you can see, the rep-tile of order 4 is also a rep-tile of order 9 in the above figures: Compare the L-shaped figure at row 2 column 1 and one at row 3 and column 1, and compare two trapezoids at row 1 and row 3.

As I know, Golomb found that a few rep-tiles of order 9 which are not of order 4. But, those examples are not simple closed curves.

[image: Golomb's fish-like rep-tile]

So, my questions:

(1) Is any rep-tile of order 4 always of order 9?

(2) If a rep-tile of order 9 is a simple close curve, is it also of order 4?

Comment: Related questions are discussed in Viorel Nitica, Rep-tiles revisited, MASS selecta, 205-217, Amer Math Soc, MR2027179 (2004j:52020).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! But, I don't have Nitica's paper and Google Books does not provide the whole paper. :-( Could you let me know the answer before I purchase the book.

Comment: All I know about the paper is what I read in Math Reviews, and that wasn't all that detailed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK. I see. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Make a triangle from 9 triangles, remove a corner.  This shape is rep-9 but not rep 4.

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FactoryForFracTilesOfOrderFour/  --  4-fractiles often aren't 9-fractiles.

Comment: @EdPegg Wow! Thank you! I found the pattern which you said. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile#/media/File:A_selection_of_rep-tiles.gif